# How to make my GLTF file have only 1 mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, gltf

I made a simple X-shaped object from 2 cuboids and joined them together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. However, when I load them into my game engine as a GLTF file, it has more than 1 mesh. How can I make everything just one mesh?

Someone said:

> If you added two stretched cubes in blender, you can add a boolean
> (union) modifier to combine them. (Be sure to "apply" that modifier).
> If you scaled the cubes in blender, you might also need to "apply" the
> scale as well.

What does that mean?

[image: quad.gltf#Mesh0/Primitive0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about *Boolean Modifiers* [in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html).

> If you added two stretched cubes in blender, you can add a boolean
> (union) modifier to combine them. (Be sure to "apply" that modifier).
> If you scaled the cubes in blender, you might also need to "apply" the
> scale as well.

When using *Boolean Modifiers*, objects with a scale other than $(1,1,1)$ can cause problems. This can be caused when you stretch objects in *Object Mode* instead of *Edit Mode*, so pay attention to the scale before using *Boolean Modifiers*. You need to apply the scale by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale* which will normalize the scale back to $(1,1,1)$ while keeping its Dimensions.

[image]

Then select the first object and under *Modifier Properties* add a *Boolean Modifier* to it. In the Boolean Modifier's settings, set its mode to *Union* and pick the second object to complete the union. Under the `^` icon, click *Apply* to apply the modifier to make the unioned mesh final as one.

[image]

Don't forget to delete the second object you used to complete the union if you don't need it anymore. Then you can export the single-meshed object as GLTF format.

Comment: awesome, it worked. I woulnd't know how to do without the video, thank you very much!

Comment: yeah these gif animations are really cool. glad i could help! :)